# Wordpress javascript relative path in a post

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cocos2d-iphone

I got a site: XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com

and I uploaded a directory with js files in:

XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/JsTestFolder

some files in it:
XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/JsTestFolder/index.html

XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/JsTestFolder/boot-html5.js

XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/JsTestFolder/cocos2d-html5.min.js

......

in the JsTestFolder folder I have a index.html containing a canvas tag

I can run the demo successfully by accessing XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/JsTestFolder/index.html

but now I want to embed it (the canvas) in a post in wordpress.

So I create a post with the content:

```
<div style="......">
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="320" height="480"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="boot-html5.js"></script>
```

and it failed to load the "boot-html5.js" file so I changed the content to:

```
<script src="/JsTestFolder/boot-html5.js"></script>
```

and this time the "boot-html5.js" was loaded sucessfully but ~

the content of boot-html5.js:

```
(function () {
    var d = document;
    var c = {
        COCOS2D_DEBUG:2, //0 to turn debug off, 1 for basic debug, and 2 for full debug
        //......
        tag:'gameCanvas', //the dom element to run cocos2d on
        SingleEngineFile:'cocos2d-html5.min.js',
        //......
```

you can see it reference some other js file using the relative path and the console shows the error:

```
http://XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/cocos2d-html5.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

well the file is in http://XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/JsTestFolder ~

Apparently the browser(?) is taking the "http://XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/" as root path not the "http://XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com//JsTestFolder".

so how can I get this thing to work without changing all my js files to use a "absolute path"?

Any advice would be appreciated, thatnks:)

Answer (score 0):

1) where is SingleEngineFile used in file?

2) try to change from

```
SingleEngineFile:'cocos2d-html5.min.js'
```

to

```
SingleEngineFile:'/cocos2d-html5.min.js'
```

Comment: yep, I know that changing this might make the error above disappeared but the point is ~ in all my js script I'am using the relative path, I don't want to change all that to "/" ("absolute path")

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
<script src="/JsTestFolder/boot-html5.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="../boot-html5.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="/boot-html5.js"></script>
```

Comment: "../boot-html5.js" and "/boot-html5.js" both won't work since the "current path" is "XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com" ~  and there is no file such as "XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/boot-html5.js" not to mention the "../" of "XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com" ~

Comment: you index file is in XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/JsTestFolder/index.html or XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/index.html?

Comment: Index file ?  well it's "XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com/JsTestFolder/index.html" but now I am trying to embed everything in a post so I'm not using it anymore ...